# Why foreground process is faster than background process in UNIX server

Tags: java, unix

We have Java application which we will be running on a UNIX server. To run it in the foreground we use below code and place it in file

```
#! /bin/ksh

/usr/java14_64/bin/java -classpath
/clocal/mptsgrp/user/mptsuser/configcfa/classes:/clocal/mptsgrp/user/mptsuser/configcfa/mqjavalib/xerces.jar::$CLASSPATH
-Djava.library.path=/usr/lpp/mqm/lib:/clocal/udb/db2inst1/sqllib/java/sqlj.zip:/clocal/udb/db2inst1/sqllib/java/db2qgjava.jar:/clocal/udb/db2inst1/sqllib/java/Common.jar:/clocal/udb/db2inst1/sqllib/java/db2umplugin.jar:/clocal/udb/db2inst1/sqllib/java/db2policy.jar:/clocal/udb/db2inst1/sqllib/java/db2dbgm.jar:/clocal/udb/db2inst1/sqllib/java/db2jcc_license_cu.jar:/clocal/udb/db2inst1/sqllib/java/db2jcc_javax.jar:/clocal/udb/db2inst1/sqllib/java/db2java.zip:/clocal/udb/db2inst1/sqllib/java/db2jcc.jar:/usr/mqm/java/lib:/clocal/udb/db2inst1/sqllib/lib:/clocal/mptsgrp/user/mptsuser/mqjavalib:/clocal/mptsgrp/user/mptsuser/mqjavalib/com.ibm.mq.jar:/clocal/mptsgrp/user/mptsuser/mqjavalib/com.ibm.mqbind.jar:/clocal/mptsgrp/user/mptsuser/mqjavalib/com.ibm.mqjms.jar:/clocal/mptsgrp/user/mptsuser/mqjavalib/jms.jar:/clocal/mptsgrp/user/mptsuser/mqjavalib
-Dcfa.config.file=/clocal/mptsgrp/user/mptsuser/configcfa/9hpcfa3/config/build_9hpcfa3.properties
-Xms16m -Xmx64m Main
```

To run from background we use below code and place it in file:

```
#! /bin/ksh

nohup /usr/java14_64/bin/java -classpath
/clocal/mptsgrp/user/mptsuser/configcfa/classes:/clocal/mptsgrp/user/mptsuser/configcfa/mqjavalib/xerces.jar::$CLASSPATH
-Djava.library.path=/usr/lpp/mqm/lib:/clocal/udb/db2inst1/sqllib/java/sqlj.zip:/clocal/udb/db2inst1/sqllib/java/db2qgjava.jar:/clocal/udb/db2inst1/sqllib/java/Common.jar:/clocal/udb/db2inst1/sqllib/java/db2umplugin.jar:/clocal/udb/db2inst1/sqllib/java/db2policy.jar:/clocal/udb/db2inst1/sqllib/java/db2dbgm.jar:/clocal/udb/db2inst1/sqllib/java/db2jcc_license_cu.jar:/clocal/udb/db2inst1/sqllib/java/db2jcc_javax.jar:/clocal/udb/db2inst1/sqllib/java/db2java.zip:/clocal/udb/db2inst1/sqllib/java/db2jcc.jar:/usr/mqm/java/lib:/clocal/udb/db2inst1/sqllib/lib:/clocal/mptsgrp/user/mptsuser/mqjavalib:/clocal/mptsgrp/user/mptsuser/mqjavalib/com.ibm.mq.jar:/clocal/mptsgrp/user/mptsuser/mqjavalib/com.ibm.mqbind.jar:/clocal/mptsgrp/user/mptsuser/mqjavalib/com.ibm.mqjms.jar:/clocal/mptsgrp/user/mptsuser/mqjavalib/jms.jar:/clocal/mptsgrp/user/mptsuser/mqjavalib
-Dcfa.config.file=/clocal/mptsgrp/user/mptsuser/configcfa/9hpcfa3/config/build_9hpcfa3.properties
-Xms16m -Xmx64m Main 1> /dev/null &
```

In our application we are not sure but the background process seems 20-30% slower when processing data compared to the foreground process. We will be writing lot of information into log.

Comment: The only relevant difference I see is that you don't actually do any IO in the "background" case: all output of your application is simply discarded, while in the other case you say you "place it in a file": that takes time, especially if there's a lot of it.

Comment: both FG and BG processs are placed in the file and ran expicitly, How to do IO sorry i am new to unix so am asking , Please explain how to use IO such that java program runs fast . but again why is Back ground is slow compared to forground

Comment: Ok, and how do you call them? What happens with the output in the foreground case? Does it get printed to the terminal? Then you've got your problem: the terminal is slowing down your application.

Comment: What kind of "Unix" is this? There are a lot of them...

Comment: i just run the file and it will start the java program . Both FG and BG are running same program 1 )When it starts the java program in FG it will show output in consol and write into log file . 2) when i run in BG it will run program in back ground and it will write output in log file . but again why is Back ground is slow compared to forground

Comment: @gyro , I am not sure but in server i am unix to run these files such my java program runs.

Comment: How are you measuring the speed difference?

Comment: If there is a lot of output (how big is the log file? Does it contain the same content as what is printed to the console), then that output can indeed explain the difference. Try running your application with the `time` command (both in BG and FG) to check that.

Comment: @user2936008 the point about IO is that nohup writes your program's output to a file called nohup.out -- if you discard its output by redirecting it to /dev/null and it runs faster, than that was the problem :) (ps: you can find which unix variant you're using with the uname command, possibly "uname -a")